# Where are the error logs of a Ruby via mod_passenger module for cpanel in apache?

Tags: node.js, apache, module, cpanel, vps

I installed an app with the application manager in cpanel and I don´t know where can I find the errors log, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple but I see a lot of people is having the same issue, the problem was I was not pointing to the proper directory when I set up the app in the application manager in cpanel, you should select the directory where exactly your app.js is located, for example my app.js was located inside home/server/src and I was pointing to home/server because the  package.js was there, also you should select development in the application manager when you set up the app otherwise you don´t see the node.js errors just a short passenger description, after that you will be able to see the errors in your web browser just  writing your app  routes like you were checking any other site.